# R: Tibble Conversions

Tags: r, date, keras, time-series, data-manipulation

I am using the R programming language. I am following this tutorial over here: https://blogs.rstudio.com/ai/posts/2018-06-25-sunspots-lstm/

I am trying to prepare my data in the same way as this example over here:

```
# Core Tidyverse
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)
library(forcats)

# Time Series
library(timetk)
library(tidyquant)
library(tibbletime)

# Visualization
library(cowplot)

# Preprocessing
library(recipes)

# Sampling / Accuracy
library(rsample)
library(yardstick) 

# Modeling
library(keras)
library(tfruns)

#here is what I am trying to copy 

sun_spots <- datasets::sunspot.month %>%
    tk_tbl() %>%
    mutate(index = as_date(index)) %>%
    as_tbl_time(index = index)


sun_spots
# A time tibble: 3,177 x 2
# Index: index
   index      value
   <date>     <dbl>
 1 1749-01-01  58  
 2 1749-02-01  62.6
 3 1749-03-01  70  
 4 1749-04-01  55.7
 5 1749-05-01  85  
 6 1749-06-01  83.5
 7 1749-07-01  94.8
 8 1749-08-01  66.3
 9 1749-09-01  75.9
10 1749-10-01  75.5
# ... with 3,167 more rows
```

In this example, the formatted data is of dimension 3,177 x 2.

I figured, that I should be able to simulate data in a similar form (using the same names as the data in the tutorial):

```
index = seq(as.Date("1749/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")


index <- format(as.Date(index), "%Y/%m/%d")

value <- rnorm(97520,27,2.1)

final_data <- data.frame(index, value)


y.mon<-aggregate(value~format(as.Date(index),
                              format="%Y/%m"),data=final_data, FUN=sum)

y.mon$index = y.mon$`format(as.Date(index), format = "%Y/%m")`
y.mon$`format(as.Date(index), format = "%Y/%m")` = NULL



#resulting file is y.mon
```

Now, when I try to convert my file to the required format:

```
 y.mon_mod <- y.mon%>%
     tk_tbl() %>%
     mutate(index = as_date(index)) %>%
     as_tbl_time(index = index)
```

I get the following error:

```
  Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `index`.
x 'origin' must be supplied
i Input `index` is `as_date(index)`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
In tk_tbl.data.frame(.) :
  Warning: No index to preserve. Object otherwise converted to tibble successfully.
```

Does anyone know why this error happens? I checked my environment and it says that the "namespace" library has been loaded. Is it because my "date" (index) variable is not in the correct format? Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: `y.mon` is an object that your code generated, not an object in the `datasets` package. So just get rid of the `datasets::` before `y.mon` and the code should work.

Comment: To add to what @neilfws said above, whenever you see a name followed by `::` it means that you're calling a function or object from the package before the `::`. So `datasets::sunspot.month` means "from the sunspots package, use the object sunspots.month." You created the object `y.mon` and it doesn't exist in the package `sunspots`, hence the error "Error: 'y.mon' is not an exported object from 'namespace:datasets'."

Comment: thank you for your reply! I tried the following code: y.mon_mod <- y.mon%>%
    tk_tbl() %>%
    mutate(index = as_date(index)) %>%
    as_tbl_time(index = index); and i got the following error: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `index`.
x 'origin' must be supplied
i Input `index` is `as_date(index)`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
In tk_tbl.data.frame(.) :
  Warning: No index to preserve. Object otherwise converted to tibble successfully.  ...maybe the date is in the wrong format?

Comment: thanks you both of you for your comments! i will remove the ::datasets command from the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `index` column such that it can be converted to date object.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tibbletime)
library(timetk)

y.mon %>%
  mutate(index = paste0(index, '/01')) %>%
  tk_tbl() %>%
  mutate(index = as_date(index)) %>%
  as_tbl_time(index = index) ->  y.mon
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This seems to work for now, but when I follow the tutorial (https://blogs.rstudio.com/ai/posts/2018-06-25-sunspots-lstm/), p2 <- y.mon %>%
    filter_time("start" ~ "1800") %>%
    ggplot(aes(index, value)) +
    geom_line(color = palette_light()[[1]], alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_point(color = palette_light()[[1]]) +
    geom_smooth(method = "loess", span = 0.2, se = FALSE) +
    theme_tq() +
    labs(
        title = "1749 to 1759 (Zoomed In To Show Changes over the Year)",
        caption = "y"
    )  i get an error: Error: Object is not of class `tbl_time`.

Comment: Would something like this work? y.mon = as.tbl_time(y.mon)?

Comment: you need to assign the output back to `y.mon` above.